# How do I get the correct Image url from discord using web3auth

Tags: javascript, next.js, discord

Scenario is - I can login using Discord as a social login in web3auth. I get the user name and profileImage. But the image url looks like this

`https://cdn.discord.com/embed/avatars/0.png`

this url doesn't work. It produces this error in console

> FetchError: request to https://cdn.discord.com/embed/avatars/0.png failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cdn.discord.com

If I paste this in search engine then I get this

> This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in cdn.discord.com.
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `cdn.discord.com` doesn't exist. Their actual URL seems to be `cdn.discordapp.com` are you sure you posted the right URL? If so, Discord gives you the wrong information. I see no issue on your side. You can contact them or attempt to manually replace the addresses and it might work.

If you meant to post `cdn.discordapp.com` instead, then you are likely encountering DNS issues with your machine.

Comment: Thanks @vfioox `cdn.discordapp.com` worked. But actually https://cdn.discord.com/embed/avatars/0.png is what I'm getting from the web3auth, seem I need to change url using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing this,

We have fixed this issue on our end. The `profileImage` field of `getUserInfo()` will return the new CDN URL.